# HTML loader in AIR no longer correctly loads facebook authorization screen

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, air

I have a standalone Adobe AIR application which uses the HTMLloader to embed a webpage and thereby access the Facebook login.

When a user first uses the application thery are first presented with a FB login screen, and then a FB authorization screen, asking if the user wants to share the uploaded image with their friends.

Up until recently everything worked fine.
But it seems that facebook has changed the way the authorization popup displays so my htmlloader no longer can 'see it'. I get a blank page.

The application sees
[image]

But should see
[image]

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question

Supplying an optional userAgent string when I first call login returns an older version of the permissions dialog which renders correctly